# Пример из документации (классы обертки)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Unboxing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = new Integer(-8);

        // 1. Unboxing through method invocation
        int absVal = absoluteValue(i);
        System.out.println("absolute value of " + i + " = " + absVal);

        List<Double> ld = new ArrayList<>();
        ld.add(3.1416);    // Π is autoboxed through method invocation.

        // 2. Unboxing through assignment
        double pi = ld.get(0);
        System.out.println("pi = " + pi);
    }

    public static int absoluteValue(int i) {
        return (i < 0) ? -i : i;
    }
}
```

До JDK 5 было `Integer i = new Integer(-8);` 
А в JDK 5 сделали, `Integer i = -8;` 
А почему я даже в документации увидел такой пример

Comment: Не понятен ваше вопрос... Почему увидели? Прочитали ) Что вы хотите в ответе получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражения не равнозначны,

```java
Integer i = -8
```

присвоит `i` кешированный экземпляр `-8`, тогда как

```java
Integer i = new Integer(-8)
```

создаст новый.

Тем не менее оба варианта вполне рабочие, за исключением того, что их сравнение не даст `true`

```
Integer i = -8;
Integer j = Integer.valueOf(-8);
Integer k = new Integer(-8);
System.out.println(i == j); // true
System.out.println(i == k); // false
```

Но на такое сравнение все равно рассчитывать нельзя, потому, что не все экземпляры `Integer` кешируются,

```java
Integer i = -800;
Integer j = Integer.valueOf(-800);
Integer k = new Integer(-800);
System.out.println(i == j); // false
System.out.println(i == k); // false
```

а сравнение с помощью `equals` работает корректно.

```java
System.out.println(i.equals(j)); // true
System.out.println(i.equals(k)); // true
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/329498/     здесь написано мол это тоже самое только до JDK 5 и после JDK 5, как понимать?

Comment: А почему код зачеркивает и показывает мол так уже не рекомендуется делать

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Там не написано, что это одно и то же, просто начиная с `JDK 5` так делать можно, раньше было нельзя, а не рекомендуется как раз потому, что `Integer i = -8` почти наверняка будет эффективнее за счет кеширования. Не считая этого (и при условии использования правильных сравнений) разницы между ними нет.

Comment: Получается если я хочу создать Integer переменную получается я должен сделать вот так? Integer a = Integer.valueOf(i);

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван достаточно простого `Integer a = i` вне зависимости от того, какого типа `i` - `int` или `Integer`, это и есть "нововведение" `JDK 5`

Comment: Получается Integer a = 1; я могу так объявлять и не будет проблем, да? Просто не очень понял кешированный экземпляр

Comment: Да, проблем не будет, этот код автоматически под будет транслирован в `Integer a = Integer.valueOf(1)`. А насчет [кеширования](https://habr.com/ru/post/104231/) - экземпляры `Integer` для небольших числел по модулю (-128..127) создаются заранее и потом используются повторно в программе не напрягая сборщик мусора и не отнимая время на их повторное создание. Т.е. `valueOf` (в том числе неявные его вызовы) не всегда возвращает новый объект, иногда просто достает подходящий из пула.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, на учебе дают информацию из википедии и когда спрашиваешь уже вот так как вас углубленно, учителя ничего не могут сказать, вот мучась, спасибо вам большое за такой открытый ответ <3

Comment: Удачи в самостоятельном обучении. Знания приобретенные по собственному сознательному желанию, а не потому, что того требует учебная программа, куда ценнее, и так просто не забываются.